# Dynamic domain for many2one field without onchange

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-16

I need to add dynamic domain for many2one field based another(bool) field **without onchange function** .. my code below doesn't work ..

```
is_bus_registered = fields.Boolean(
    string='Bus Registered',
    required=False)

def _domain_att_policy(self):
    if self.is_bus_registered:
        policies = self.env['hr.attendance.policy'].search([('is_bus_registered', '=', True)]).ids
        return [('id', 'in', policies)]
    else:
        policies = self.env['hr.attendance.policy'].search([('is_bus_registered', '=', False)]).ids
        return [('id', 'in', policies)]

att_policy_id = fields.Many2one('hr.attendance.policy', string='Attendance Policy', domain=_domain_att_policy)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the field `is_bus_registered` in your form view, the following field definition should be enough:

```py
att_policy_id = fields.Many2one(
    comodel_name='hr.attendance.policy',
    string='Attendance Policy',
    domain='[("is_bus_registered", "=", is_bus_registered)]')
```

Have following in mind: if a user sets a policy with `is_bus_registered==False` and changes `is_bus_registered` afterwards to `True`, the policy won't change without an onchange event. That could lead to wrong policies. So using or definining an onchange event probably is not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

I added another field many2many with onchange

```
@api.onchange('is_bus_registered')
def _onchange_is_bus_registered(self):
    for rec in self:
        if rec.is_bus_registered:
            rec.att_policy_id = False
            policy_ids = []
            policies = self.env['hr.attendance.policy'].search(
                [('is_bus_registered', '=', True)])
            for policy in policies:
                policy_ids.append(policy.id)
            rec.att_policy_ids = policy_ids
        else:
            rec.att_policy_id = False
            policy_ids = []
            policies = self.env['hr.attendance.policy'].search(
                [('is_bus_registered', '=', False)])
            for policy in policies:
                policy_ids.append(policy.id)
            rec.att_policy_ids = policy_ids


att_policy_ids = fields.Many2many('hr.attendance.policy', string='Attendance Policy')
```

and then added in form view but invisible and put it in static domain in many2one field .. it works fine

```
<field name="att_policy_ids" invisible="1"/>
<field name="att_policy_id" required="1" domain="[('id','in',att_policy_ids)]"/>
```